# Get data attribute value from Button on click

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to see the data on

```
<div id="data">
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="margin:5px; data-SenEmail="email@email.com" class="btn btn-primary text-white item_sms" type="button" >Button</button>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery code

```
$('#data').on('click','.item_email',function(){
    var SenEmail = $(this).data('SenEmail');

    console.log(SenEmail, "Hello, world!");
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firstly**, you are declaring `item_sms` instead of `item_email` class.

**Secondly**, your `style="margin:5px; data-SenEmail="email@email.com"` are missing `"`, You need to fix it like this `style="margin:5px;" data-SenEmail="email@email.com"`

**Thirdly**, You are achieving a list of item, so you need to get an index of the item that you want it, like `$(this)[0]`

**Finally**, You can only get data from `data` attribute via **lower case**, like `data('senemail')` instead of `data('SenEmail')`

Check my code below:

```js
$('#data').on('click','.item_email',function(){
    var SenEmail = $($(this)[0]).data('senemail');

    console.log(SenEmail, "Hello, world!");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="margin:5px;" data-SenEmail="email@email.com" class="btn btn-primary text-white item_email" type="button">Button
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You are such an amazing person. you details your solution and it worked perfectly. Thanks